# simple_wsgi_app, проблема с запуском простого wsgi приложения

Tags: python, wsgi

Права на обоих 777.

Приложение s_wsgi_app.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5    
def simple_wsgi_app(environ, start_response):
            status = '200 OK'
            headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]
            start_response(status, headers)
            return ['Hello world!']
```

Сервер wsgi.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from aaa import s_wsgi_app


httpd = make_server('', 8000, s_wsgi_app)
print('Started app serving on port 8000...')
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Сервер запускается :

```
Started app serving on port 8000...
```

и после того как я перехожу по http://127.0.0.1:8000/
в окне браузера пишет: `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2017 02:00:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2017 02:00:06] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

(почему-то в результатах выводится 2 одинаковых traceback'a, за одно обращение к адресу)

Answer (score 1):

1. Надо импортировать не весь модуль, а конкретную функцию:

`from s_wsgi_app import simple_wsgi_app`

2. Добавить кодирование в двоичный код :

   `return ['Hello world!'.encode('utf-8')]`

Comment: здесь это не важно, но в общем случае, если вы utf-8 используете, то в Content-Type кодировку также пропишите: `'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'` иначе кракозябры можно получить. Потестируйте со строкой `'Привет, мир!'`.